# Delete a column from a double array

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

I'm stuck here.  I've got a matrix of size NxN stored in a double array.  Then I want to delete a given column, lets say the first column.  So I created a new double array of size NxN-1 and copy the values from the first matrix to the second one, except the 1st column of course.  But then I want to set the first array to be the second array.  I am blanking here.

```
double matrix[N][N]
//fill up the matrix code here...


// remove first column of array
double newMatrix[N][N-1];
for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for(j = 1; j < N; j++){
        newMatrix[i][j-1] = matrix[i][j];
    }
}
matrix = newMatrix; // how do I set this correctly?  Do I need to realloc the first array?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign arrays in C, which I assume that your compiler tells you. To do such dynamic memory management, you will need to use pointers instead of arrays. I suggest you read up on how `malloc()` and `free()` work so that you can do what you want.

**Edit:**

Another solution comes to mind if you are only *removing* columns (or rows): keep track of the number of rows and columns used in the array. Then you can remove a row or column within the original array without creating a copy first. Just move the data past the delete column (or row) to the left (or up) then decrement your size counters. (I hope this make sense. If not let me know and I'll elaborate.)

Comment: Okay so if I dynamically allocate the array then when I want to delete the first column I can just shift the values over and then free the last column.  Does that sound like the right logic?

Comment: @jimjohnjim You might be able to do something like that depending on how you allocate the array. Do you only want to delete columns or will you be deleting rows as well?

Comment: I need to delete columns sometimes and delete rows other times. So to delete the last row I can just free(matrix[ROW-1]) correct?  But the same does not apply to the column because each row has a last column.  So there I'm trying to, once everything is shift over, realloc each matrix[i] to be 1 size smaller.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @jimjohnjim Be sure to set `matrix[ROW-1] = NULL`. For columns, you will need to reallocate each row and copy data over with the deleted column removed. Note that this all needs to be done with pointers since you can't reallocate an array.

Answer (score 1):

like Code-guru said    malloc() and    free() should help alot, but if u simply wanted to delete the last column the you wouldn't need two arrays:

```
double matrix[2][3] = {1,2,3,4,5,6}; //declaring a 2 by 3 matrix 



for (i=0;i<2;i++) //rows
{   
    for (j=0;j<3-1;j++) //columns - 1
    {
        printf("%.1f ",matrix[i][j]); //I chose to display matrix...
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of accessing elements from array[i][j], one might opt to access elements from `array + stride_x[x] + stride_y[y]`; where array is originally introduced as `double matrix[N*N];` or `double *matrix = malloc(sizeof(double)*N*N);`.

The stride_y[x] would originally contain offsets of columns for all rows: 0 1 2 3 4 ... N-1 and stride_y[y] would contain similar offsets multiplied with original row width 0 N 2*N 3*N..

From these 1-D arrays one can more effortlessly delete or exchange complete rows and columns, which may come handy in eg. recursive implementation of determinant calculation / Gauss Jordan elimination.